# Datatables, Setting a link with URL variable from desired column retreived from json

Tags: javascript, json, variables, hyperlink, datatables

In the Table I got 2 columns that I want the same link with attached ID from the item. The frist one from the ID it selft works, But I what to attach the ID to the link of the name it self.

Below is my code to initialize the datatable.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "ajax": "data.txt",
                "processing": true,

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id", "name": "id",
                        "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                            return '<a href="detail.php?id='+data+'"> '+data+' </a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "dob", "name": "dob",
                        "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                                return '<img src="/img/userpics/'+data+'">';
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "name", "name": "name",
                        "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                             var varempid = THIS_IS_WHAT_I_CANT_DO ;
                             return '<a href="detail.php?id='+varempid+'"> '+data+' </a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "position", "name": "position" },
                    { "data": "status", "name": "status" }
                ],


                responsive: true,
                'iDisplayLength': 6,
                "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],

                "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, 1000, -1], [50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],
                "pageLength": 50

            } );
        } );

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get all the data from the row inside the `JsonResultRow`. You can try `console.log(JsonResultRow)` to view all the data for the row.

```
{ "data": "name",
  "name": "name",
  "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
              var varempid = JsonResultRow['id'];
              return '<a href="detail.php?id='+varempid+'"> '+data+' </a>';
            }
},
```

Comment: JsonResultRow['id'] - It Works now. This solves my problem. TY.

Comment: Good to hear. :)